# Finding all lattice points in an $n$-dimensional hypercube

Tags: integer-programming, integer-lattices

I have an $n$-dimensional axis-aligned hypercube and a lattice generated by $n$ linearly independent vectors, both in $\mathbb{Z}^n$. My wish is to find all points of the lattice which fall in the interior of the hypercube.

Currently I accomplish this by reducing the lattice using [LLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm), using the reduced basis to find a small parallelepiped entirely containing the hypercube, then iterating through every lattice point within this parallelepiped, checking if each is contained within the desired region.

Of course, this is a very naive way of doing things, and generates a lot of unnecessary work for even semi-large $n$. The question is then what the most efficient (checking the least number of lattice points) way of finding all points of a (reduced) lattice contained within a hypercube is. If I only want one point does it get easier?

Comment: What you're doing already sounds like a very reasonable approach: (1) start with basis reduction (LLL, BKZ), and (2) enumerate short combinations using this better basis. This is basically how people also solve the shortest vector problem, which is equivalent to solving your problem but for balls, rather than cubes. Maybe you could potentially do slightly better with basis reduction/enumeration algorithms for the $\ell_{\infty}$-norm, but I'm not sure practical algorithms for that exist.

Comment: Yes, since posting this question I have switched to BKZ and began using some basic linear programming to do the enumeration which greatly sped up the problem for my use case. I have wondered about reduction algorithms for the $ℓ_∞$-norm, and I suspect they would be superior. Do you know of any at all? I found the literature lacking when I looked briefly and cannot see a natural way to modify existing lattice reduction techniques to work in other norms. Perhaps this is worth another question.

Comment: As far as I know, no efficient algorithms are known for the infinity norm, other than some theoretical results which likely have no practical value. Efficient algorithms for the infinity norm would impact security estimates for lattice-based cryptography, but I think all current security analyses assume that the best way to find a short vector in the infinity norm is just to find a short vector in the Euclidean norm.